# Webpack preserve require

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to conditionally import stuff in js, using webpack. Consider the following:

**fetch.js**

```
const findFetch = () => {
  if (window.process && window.process.electron) {
    // electron (requirement to use node-fetch here)
    return require('node-fetch')
  } else if (window.fetch) {
    // browser
    return fetch
  }
  // old browser
  return () => Promise.reject(
    new Error('Fetch api not available. Please update your browser!')
  )
}

export default findFetch()
```

Now I don't want any of the `http` (and other node modules, that come with that dependency) bundled into  my client code.

Is there a way to preserve an import/require? By preserve I mean don't mess with that part of the code, don't transform it, just leave it as it is?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. What is the problem exactly? Do you need help in separating your node modules from your client code?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear. I would like to keep the `require('node-fetch')` statement intact.

Comment: And then separate the node-fetch module from the rest of your code?

Comment: @RickvanOsta exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You're able to specify which package goes in which bundle in your `webpack.config.js` using the *entry* option.

```
entry: {
  app: "./src/app.js",
  vendor: ["node-fetch", "more", "libraries", "go", "here"]
},
output: {
  filename: "[name].bundle.js",
  path: path.resolve(__dirname)
}
plugins: {
  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor")
}
```

The above code makes sure you get two bundles. A bundle named `vendor.bundle.js` containing *node-fetch* and other libraries you'd want to include, and a bundle named `app.bundle.js` containing the rest.